# Determine the constants $m$ and $k$ such that $f'(0)$ exists?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Determine the constants $m$ and $k$ such that

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x^2+kx+m & \text{for }x<0 \\
6\tan(7x)+10\cos(9x) & \text{for }x\ge 0
\end{cases}$$
is differentiable at $x=0$.

Answer (score 5):

To be differentiable at $x=0$ note first it must be continuous, and so our limits from either side must agree:$$\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)\\\lim_{x\to0^+}(6\tan7x+10\cos9x)=\lim_{x\to0^-}(x^2+kx+m)\\10=m$$Similarly, you need both derivatives to agree at $x=0$ as well:$$\left[\frac{d}{dx}(6\tan7x+10\cos9x)\right]_{x=0}=\left[\frac{d}{dx}(x^2+kx+m)\right]_{x=0}\\ [42\sec^27x-90\sin9x]_{x=0}=[2x+k]_{x=0}\\42=k$$

---

Note you could also observe the Taylor expansion of $6\tan7x+10\cos9x=10+42x+O(x^2)$ ;-)
Just to appreciate how similar these two functions are near $x=0$ observe:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  you need the function values and the slopes to agree at $0$.  So evaluate each expression at zero and set them equal.  Then evaluate the first derivative of each expression at zero and set those equal.  This gives two equations in two unknowns ($m,k)$